# How to create html offline application manifest in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to port ASP.NET MVC4 HTML offline application to .NET 5.
It should allow to enter order without internet connenction and send it to MVC 5 controller over internet if connection is present.

It has manifest controller

```
namespace Store.Controllers
{
    public class MobileOrderController : ControllerBase
        {

        public async Task<IActionResult> Manifest()
        {
            return new AppCacheResult(new[] {
                BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jquery")
            },
           fingerprint: BundleTable.Bundles
                           .FingerprintsOf("~/bundles/jquery"));
        }
    }
     }

        public class AppCacheResult : IActionResult
        {
            public AppCacheResult(
                IEnumerable<string> cacheAssets,
                IEnumerable<string> networkAssets = null,
                IDictionary<string, string> fallbackAssets = null,
                string fingerprint = null)
            {
                if (cacheAssets == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("cacheAssets");
                }
    
                CacheAssets = cacheAssets.ToList();
    
                if (!CacheAssets.Any())
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        "Cached url cannot be empty.", "cacheAssets");
                }
    
                NetworkAssets = networkAssets ?? new List<string>();
                FallbackAssets = fallbackAssets ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Fingerprint = fingerprint;
            }
    
            protected IEnumerable<string> CacheAssets { get; private set; }
    
            protected IEnumerable<string> NetworkAssets { get; private set; }
    
            protected IDictionary<string, string> FallbackAssets
            {
                get;
                private set;
            }
    
            protected string Fingerprint { get; private set; }
    
            public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
            {
                if (context == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
                }
    
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    
                response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.Zero);
                response.ContentType = "text/cache-manifest";
                response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; //  needs to be utf-8
                response.Write(GenerateContent());
            }
    
            protected virtual string GenerateHeader()
            {
                return "CACHE MANIFEST" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
    
            protected virtual string GenerateFingerprint()
            {
                return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Fingerprint) ?
                    string.Empty :
                    Environment.NewLine +
                    "# " + Fingerprint +
                    Environment.NewLine;
            }
    
            protected virtual string GenerateCache()
            {
                var result = new StringBuilder();
    
                result.AppendLine();
                result.AppendLine("CACHE:");
                CacheAssets.ToList().ForEach(a => result.AppendLine(a));
    
                return result.ToString();
            }
    
            protected virtual string GenerateNetwork()
            {
                var result = new StringBuilder();
    
                result.AppendLine();
                result.AppendLine("NETWORK:");
    
                var networkAssets = NetworkAssets.ToList();
    
                if (networkAssets.Any())
                {
                    networkAssets.ForEach(a => result.AppendLine(a));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AppendLine("*");
                }
    
                return result.ToString();
            }
    
            protected virtual string GenerateFallback()
            {
                if (!FallbackAssets.Any())
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
    
                var result = new StringBuilder();
    
                result.AppendLine();
                result.AppendLine("FALLBACK:");
    
                foreach (var pair in FallbackAssets)
                {
                    result.AppendLine(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
                }
    
                return result.ToString();
            }
    
            private string GenerateContent()
            {
                var content = new StringBuilder();
    
                content.Append(GenerateHeader());
                content.Append(GenerateFingerprint());
                content.Append(GenerateCache());
                content.Append(GenerateNetwork());
                content.Append(GenerateFallback());
    
                var result = content.ToString();
    
                return result;
            }
        }
```

This causes compile error in .NET 5 since  response.Cache and response.ContentEncoding does not exis in lines

```
response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.Zero);
response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

also response.Write does not exist in line

```
response.Write(GenerateContent());
```

and BundleTable.Bundles does not exist in .NET 5

How to convert it to .NET 5 ?
Or is there better way to create HTML offline application in .NET 5 using ASP.NET MVC Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache settings you could handle in startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default30",
                new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Duration = 30
                });
        });
```

For the encoding you could use following snippet:

```
var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
mediaType.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
httpContext.Response.ContentType = mediaType.ToString();
```

responce.Write could be replaced with this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GenerateContent());        
await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes);
```

Comment: For cacing I added `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]`  attribute to Manifest controller. Will it produce the same result as MVC4 code response cahce settings ?

Comment: @Andrus Make sure, that MediaTypeHeaderValue is coming from Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers assembly. I think this attribute should do the trick too.